# get $web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, csom

This is my first time trying to use CSOM with Powershell, I would like to display the $web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId of a site.

I have created the script that will change the site Locale to en-UK which is a good if my only requirement is to do this on one site.

My aim is to go through all the sites in my tenant and gather all which don't equal '2057' into a list.

When I add Write-Host $web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId before setting the value it comes back blank, but in the script below it works fine after setting the value, any idea why?

```
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("SITEURL")

$username = 'USERACCOUNT'

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for $username" –AsSecureString

 $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)


$web = $ctx.Web;
$ctx.Load($web);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

$web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId = 2057;
$web.Update();
Write-Host $web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `RegionalSettings` object. Try the below code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("SITEURL")

$username = 'USERACCOUNT'

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for $username" –AsSecureString

$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)


$web = $ctx.Web;
$RegionalSettings = $ctx.Web.RegionalSettings
$ctx.Load($web);
$ctx.Load($RegionalSettings);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Write-Host $RegionalSettings.LocaleId

$web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId = 2057;
$web.Update();
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Write-Host $web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PnP PowerShell you could do:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url [URL] -Credentials $($Get-Credential)
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$catch = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $web -Property RegionalSettings
$web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId
```